# mod_rewrite, Adding a Condition

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ zone.php [L]
```

Right now it works pretty well. How can I make this RewriteRule not work in a certain directory?

I do not want the rule to work for anything in domain.com/manage/

Comment: you can put `RewriteEngine Off` in `manage/.htaccess`

Comment: Wow I thought this would be hard. Really good answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (?!^manage/)^.*$ /zone.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your rules inside Directory tags, i.e.:

```
<Directory "/foo">
  ... your rules here...
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition by using the `RewriteCond` keyword to apply the rule if the directory is not `manage`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/manage(/|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ zone.php [L]
```